# Redirect Wordpress tags to homepage htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, tags

I want to delete all tag product pages and I want to redirect all my wordpress product tags to homepage.

I found a lot of answers on the web and on the stackoverflow but the general answers doesn't work for me and I don't know why.

I changed the permalink in WP from tag to eticheta-produs, so my product tags looks like:
https://www.domain.tld/eticheta-produs/present
instead of default WP tags
https://www.domain.tld/tag/present

So, I tried:

```
# Redirect tag 301
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^eticheta-produs/(.*)$ http:/www.domain.tld/ [R=301,L]
```

And https:

```
# Redirect tag 301
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^eticheta-produs/(.*)$ https:/www.domain.tld/ [R=301,L]
```

I stoped caching throw litespeed plugin, I tried opening tag pages throw incognito sessions of different browsers but the redirect doesn't work.

Comment: I should also note that in your original question that your protocols are missing a `/` before the `www`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will redirect anything from `eticheta-produs` and its subfolders to your root domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/eticheta-produs/(.*)$ http://domain\.tld/
```

Comment: Thank you Justin,

That double slash was a typo.
Doesn't work with http:// domain\.tld/, that backslash crash, but without it, works perfectly.

Comment: The backslash in the middle is used to escape the period.  It's not 100% necessary in most instances.  If you found the answer to be helpful, please remember to mark it as correct and upvote.  Thanks!!